# Adding text in TikZ-picture at position determined by combining tangent and intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, tikz-node

## Question

> How to add text to arbitrary positions in TikZ-pictures relative to
>   certain objects (maybe even following their shape) ?

### Situation

I have combined two solutions to Tikz-questions found here on stackexchange, namely:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940/74942
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58216/74942

Even though I could create the desired drawing, I do not fully understand the provided solutions. Therefore the following
**problem** came up: I was unable to figure out the right way to insert some text (a is not close enough and could be rotated along the curve) as depicted in this image:

[image: desired result]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{filecontents}{projection.tikz}
    % tangent: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940/74942
    % intersection: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58216/74942
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    tangent/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,% switch on markings
            mark=
            at position #1
            with
            {
                \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    use tangent/.style={
        shift=(tangent point-#1),
        x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
        y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
    },
    use tangent/.default=1
    ] % tangent

    \draw[help lines,xstep=.5,ystep=.5] (0,0) grid (4,3); %grid

    \draw [
    name path=curve,
    tangent=0.4
    ] (0,0)
    to [out=60,in=180] (2,2)
    to [out=0, in=160] (3,1.75)
    to [out=-20, in=-120] (4,3);

    \draw [blue, name path=tangent, use tangent] (-1,0) -- (2,0)
    node[sloped,inner sep=0cm,below,pos=.8,
    anchor=north west,
    minimum height=1cm,
    minimum width=1cm](N){a};

    \path [name path=proj] (N.north west)% intersection
    node (P) {b} -- (N.south west);

    \draw [name intersections={of=curve and proj}, blue] (P.center) 
    --
    (intersection-1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\input{./projection.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For text along curves see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22314/15925 .  Where do you want `a` to be?

Comment: @AndrewSwann, thank you for that hint. `a` should be where "and here" is.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, thanks again! I was able to figure it out; see the answer. Sadly I cannot upvote this comment more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15925/andrew-swann)s hint I was able to figure it out:

[image: result]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{filecontents}{projection.tikz}
    % tangent: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940/74942
    % intersection: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58216/74942
    % text along path: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22316/74942
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    tangent/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,% switch on markings
            mark=
            at position #1
            with
            {
                \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    use tangent/.style={
        shift=(tangent point-#1),
        x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
        y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
    },
    use tangent/.default=1
    ] % tangent

    \draw[help lines,xstep=.5,ystep=.5] (0,0) grid (4,3); %grid

    \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{-2.5ex}} %text along path - height from line
    \draw [
                name path=curve,
                tangent=0.4, % where tangent is set (percent of total curve)
                postaction={decorate,
                    decoration={text along path,
                        text align=center,
                        text={|\sffamily\footnotesize\myshift| and maybe here too }
                    }
                } %text command
                ] (0,0)
                    to [out=60,in=180] (2,2)
                    to [out=0, in=160] (3,1.75)
                    to [out=-20, in=-120] (4,3);

    \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}} %text along path - height from line
    \draw [blue, 
                name path=tangent,
                use tangent,
                postaction={decorate,
                    decoration={text along path,
                        text align=center,
                        text={|\sffamily\footnotesize\myshift| I want some text here }
                    }
                } %text command
                ] (-1,0) -- (2,0)
    node[sloped,inner sep=0cm,below,pos=.8,
    anchor=north west,
    minimum height=1cm,
    minimum width=1cm](N){a};

    \path [name path=proj] (N.north west)% intersection
    node (P) {b} -- (N.south west);

    \draw [ name intersections={of=curve and proj},
                blue,
                postaction={decorate,
                    decoration={text along path,
                        text align=center,
                        text={|\sffamily\tiny\myshift| and here }
                    }
                } %text command
            ] (P.center) 
    --
    (intersection-1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\input{./projection.tikz}
\end{document}
```